# Android: getDownTime registering MotionEvent from different button

Tags: android, android-button, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have two buttons, which both register touches and react according to whether the `MotionEvent` is `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_UP`.
One button uses `getDownTime()` and `getEventTime()` to time how long the button was held for. A minimal example is:

```
Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btn1_down();
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                long eventTime = event.getEventTime();
                long downTime = event.getDownTime();
                long duration = eventTime - downTime;
                btn1_up(duration);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btn2_down();
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                btn2_up();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I would have expected that I could now press, hold, and release either button in any order, and have all actions register correctly. However, when I press and hold button 2, and then repeatedly quickly tap button 1 with another finger, the durations registered for each tap on button 1 get longer and longer... seemingly timing not the duration of the tap, but the time between the initial press of button 2 and the tap. It seems to me that `getDownTime()` is for some reason using the `ACTION_DOWN` `MotionEvent` of the initial press and hold of button 2, instead of the ones from tapping on button 1.

Why is this happening?

Here is the XML of the two button:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/btn1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/btn2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried adding `android:splitMotionEvents="true"` to the `LinearLayout`, but it didn't change the behaviour.